# cannot install aptana

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I am trying to install aptan in my eclips hilios. Its giving me a wired problem. I went here and installed it

http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration

When I went to perspectives I dont see aptana there.

I tried to reinstall aptana and it said I couldnt as it is already installed.

I deleted the installation of eclipse and redid the steps and still no help.

I am not sure whats going on

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Where are you looking for the perspective? Also, if you can't get it to work you might try just downloading standalone Aptana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Helios, I would recommend trying out the new Aptana Studio 3 beta. It's in good shape, especially for a 'beta'! I've been using it as my primary IDE with additional plugins such as CFEclipse, Java Development Tools, J2EE and the Groovy plugin and had zero issues for the last month+.

Additionally, the Studio 3 beta is built on Helios' architecture, so you should be able to integrate it without any (read: too many) headaches!
http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download